# Using appended images as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a program which allows users to print Instagram photos at an event by selecting them from a feed using a touchscreen.

However, I'm struggling to use the images as selectors once I've pulled them in.

I'm fetching the images as follows:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent',
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(x in data.data){
        identifier++;
        $('div').append('<img id="image' + identifier + '" src="'+data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></img>');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

In order to output a specific image, I'll obviously need to be able to determine which image has been selected, so I'm trying to use images as selectors (in this example, `image1`). However, I can't seem to persuade the below to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image1").on("click", function(){
        window.print();
    });
});
```

It does work when I use `$("div")` as a selector, but that's obviously not much help in determining which image has been clicked.

(I haven't got round to properly outputting everything yet - hence why I'm using `window.print()`)

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `$(document).on("click",#image1", function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is you are binding the event even before the images are created. You have to bind the event just after the elements are created i.e in this case , in the success function of ajax method. **Like this**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent',
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(x in data.data){
        identifier++;
        $('div').append('<img id="image' + identifier + '" src="'+data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></img>');
        }
$("#image1").on("click", function(){
        window.print();
    });
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Tom Davies, Also ensure the ajax call is made somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching images and adding them dynamically so when the document is ready the selector `$('#image1')` is not there .

What you can do is selecting the `$("div")` and inside that div select the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div").on("click","#image1" function(){
        window.print();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good one. Like the div selector rather than document selector

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if you're actually initializing 'identifier' or not, if not then you probably are not creating a id of "image1".

That said, a much easier way to go is to just tie the click event to a selector matching all image children of the div, and then get the clicked one from the event:

$("div > img").on("click", function(e) { console.log($(this).attr('src')); })

That should log the url of the image you've associated with the tag clicked.

Comment: This has saved me a lot of time! Thank you!